Polynomials over finite field which vanish everywhere.
I am motivated by this: Let $V$ be a vector space over a field of $q$ elements with $\dim V\geq 2$ then $V$ can be written as union of $q+1$ proper subspaces.
I've written a constructive proof here.
Now, I let $\mathbb F$ be a finite field having $q$ elements and consider the vector space $\mathbb F^2$.
$\mathbb F^2$ can be written as union of $q+1$ number of one-dimensional subspaces, say, $V_0$, $V_1$, $\ldots$, $V_q$. Corresponding to each $V_i$, there is a non-zero linear functional $f_i(x_1,x_2) = a_ix_1+b_ix_2\in\mathbb F[x_1,x_2]$ s.t. $\ker f_i =V_i$ i.e., $f_i$ vanishes exactly on $V_i$.
It follows that the product of these functionals i.e., $f_0f_1\ldots f_q$ vanishes everywhere on $\mathbb F^2$.  This is a $q+1$ degree homogeneous polynomial in $\mathbb F[x_1,x_2]$.
If I did everything correctly, we come to the conclusion that:

Let $n\in\mathbb Z_{\geq 2}$. Given a field $\mathbb F$ of $q$ elements, you can find a homogeneous polynomial of degree $q+1$ in $\mathbb F[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ which vanishes everywhere on $\mathbb F^n$.

Is that right? I have never seen this result anywhere. Can anyone provide a reference to this? I would also want to see other proofs of this and related results.

Your result is correct. When applied to the decomposition from the Hagen von Eitzen's answer in the linked thread, it yields a concrete example:
$$f(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) = x_1 \cdot \prod_{c \in \mathbb{F}} (x_2 - cx_1).$$

I can also see the subspaces corresponding to each factor... $V_0={(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n):x_1=0}$, $V_c={(x_1, x_2,\ldots, x_n): x_2=cx_1}$. These are hyperspaces of $\mathbb F^n$.

I think an alternate representation of the same polynomial should be $x_1 x_2^q - x_1^q x_2$.  Which evaluates to zero everywhere since $x_2^q = x_2$ and $x_1^q = x_1$.

@DanielSchepler That's correct, nice find.

Your reasoning looks correct. A more direct way to reach the same conclusion would be:
Since $x=x^q$ for every $x\in\mathbb{F}_q$, we have
$$ x^q y = xy = x y^q $$
so $x^q y - x y^q$ is zero everywhere, and clearly homogeneous of degree $q+1$.
By the way, this factors as $xy(x^{q-1}-y^{q-1})$. With that factorization, being identically zero can alternatively be understood as: Either $x$ is zero or $y$ is zero, or both are nonzero -- and in the latter case their $(q-1)$th powers are both $1$.

And in fact $x^{q-1} - y^{q-1}$ factors as $\prod_{c \in \mathbb{F}_q^*} (x - cy)$, making this answer closely related to the one by Adayah.

Yeah, with two variables there's only that solution, up to constant factors. Namely: The $x^{q+1}$ coefficient must vanish; otherwise we wouldn't get zero at (1,0). But now the coefficient of $x^qy$ must determine the entire polynomial: If we had two distinct solutions with the same $x^qy$ coefficient, then set $y=0$ and subtract them; the result would be an everywhere zero polynomial in $x$ of degree $<q$, which is impossible.

This would have been my choice for the answer as well :-)

I've seen this result being mentioned as an aside in algebra classes, but don't have a concrete textbook reference:
There are infinitely many polynomials but only finitely many (polynomial) functions on a finite set. By the pigeonhole principle this implies that there must be two different polynomials which induce the same function on a given finite field. Their difference thus induces the zero function.
Or you could simply take the product $\prod_{a\in F}(x-a)$ of linear factors over all field elements as a concrete example.

This doesn't prove that the polynomial has degree $q+1$ or is homogeneous. Also your concrete example is zero over $\mathbb{F}$, not $\mathbb{F}^n$. Incidentally, it is equal to $x^q-x$.
